# In-sample forecast accuracy of Beta (Kalman filter)

Tags: forecasting, predictive-models, finance, kalman-filter, state-space-models

One can calculate time-varying betas (known from the CAPM) using the Kalman filter.
For example, one can calculate the in-sample forecast accuracy using the MAE.

$MAE = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T|\hat{R}_{t}-R_{t}|$

This compares the actual return with the estimated return. The estimated return $\hat{R}_{t}$ is the product of the calculated beta and the actual market return $R_{mt}$.

$\hat{R}_{t}=\hat{\beta}_{t}R_{mt}$

I would like to know if the betas used for comparison here would have to be filtered betas or predicted betas? In the papers you often see these tests, but it is never stated whether they are the filtered values or predictions (one-steap ahead forecast).

I am very appreciative of any help.

Comment: I would suggest that we estimate parameters but predict (out of sample) or fit (in sample) realizations of random variables.  Since $\hat{R}_t$ is a random variable, I would say we predict it or fit it.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm afraid I don't know exactly how you mean that. There is the possibility to filter $\beta_{t,t}$, that is the estimation including the correction step based on the observations up to time $t$. Or you can use $\beta_{t,t-1}$, which is an estimate at time t based on the data up to t-1. Which exactly do you think is the right choice for beta?

Comment: Yeah, this was just a comment on terminology, not an answer of the question. I suppose the answer can be found in the theory of finance, not statistics.

Comment: You don't have dynamics for $R_{mt}$, right? It's taken to be exogeneous? If that's the case, you have to wait until $t$ to compute an estimated $\hat{R}_t$ anyway, so there's no point in time in which you have to take the forecasted $\beta_t$ but have access to the actual $R_{mt}$, so there's not really any practical meaning to give to that expression (so, it should be the filtered $\beta$).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. $R_{mt}$ is the time varying matrix in the observation equation. Thus, this market return is known up to $t$. I am confused since the name of the test talks about forecast.

Comment: @Marv91 You seem to be referring to something specific (a paper?) but have not given any reference. I don't know what the authors did or why, I am just pointing out that one alternative isn't really meaningful. In general, CAPM is a model of asset return *conditional* on the "market return", and doesn't produce "true" forecasts anyway.

Comment: Here is the thesis to which I refer: [link](https://univerlag.uni-goettingen.de/bitstream/handle/3/isbn-978-3-941875-22-7/mergner.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)
On page 145 of the PDF file respectively 113 of the document. This issue is addressed there. Unfortunately, I cannot understand from the text whether it is actually about filtered betas or predicted.